# JFace/SWT: What is the best way to add a toolbar with Commands to a Section?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, plugin.xml

I have a Section and want to add a toolbar to it. I'm able to do it programmatically using the Actions but the requirement is to do it as much declaratively (in plugin.xml) as I can. So I'd like to define a Command and a Handler for each toolbar button but I don't know how to add them to the section's toolbar. Is there any way to do it declaratively in plugin.xml? If not, how can I do it programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to write your own extension point to define what would go in the `plugin.xml` and then write code to access the extension point registry to get the declared extensions and create the toolbar from the information.

See [Eclipse Extension Points and Extensions](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html) for some more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, that would be the last resort if everything else fails :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at how to use `org.eclipse.ui.menus extension` point. It supports adding commands/widgets to menu/popup/toolbar/trim.

```
//contributing to local toolbar

ToolBarManager localToolBarmanager = new ToolBarManager();
IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IMenuService.class);
menuService.populateContributionManager(localToolBarmanager,
    "toolbar:localtoolbar");  //id of your local toolbar
localToolBarmanager.createControl(control);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is true. But I need to add commands to a toolbar which is neither a main toolbar nor a view's toolbar but a custom toolbar created programmatically. Can I do it somehow using this extension?

Comment: I just updated my answer.take a look. it should read contributions defined for menus extension with the local toolbar id given

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of how to create a toolbar for a section, make sure the toolbar is created before `section.setClient()`.

```
protected void createToolbar(Section section) {
    ToolBarManager toolBarManager = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);
    toolBarManager.add(new Action("print") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("PRINT");
        }
    });
    createSectionToolbar(section, toolBarManager);
}

/**
 * create a toolbar in the passed section
 * 
 * @param section
 * @param toolBarManager
 */
protected void createSectionToolbar(Section section, ToolBarManager toolBarManager) {
    Composite toolbarComposite = toolkit.createComposite(section);
    toolbarComposite.setBackground(null);
    toolBarManager.createControl(toolbarComposite);
    section.clientVerticalSpacing = 0;
    section.descriptionVerticalSpacing = 0;
    section.setTextClient(toolbarComposite);
}
```

If you want to add declared commands from the `plugin.xml` to the toolbar, have a look at `CommandContributionItem`.

```
toolBarManager.add(new CommandContributionItem(new CommandContributionItemParameter(getSite(), "id", "commandId", SWT.NONE)));
```